# How to remove artifacts from a equirectangluar projection with a displacement material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, displacement

I have notice some strange behavior when rendering equirectangular images in blender 2.79b (also happens in the 2.80 alpha).
Whenever I have a material with a displacement added to it, it results in a strange artifacts at the poles of the image.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this?

Rotating the camera 180 degrees does the job because it always stays at the right side of the image, but having to render each half individually all the time is way too much of a hassle and it's clearly not the solution to the problem.

Thanks in advance!

2nv2u

I created this simple example below.

The actual render:
[image: The actual render]
Screenshot from viewer:
[image: Screenshot from viewer]
Material used:
[image: Material]